# Create a bash file for transfer file through tftp

Tags: shell, tftp

I want to create shell script to invoke tftp transfer of particular file to my local machine

this is the operation i want to do

```
tftp 172.2.22.2
get file1_in_remote location file2_in_local_machine
quit
```

but I can't make it work, because when the 1st **tftp** command executes, control will got to tftp prompt. its just loook like this

```
tftp>
```

And it wont accept the 2nd and 3rd commands i have given in the shell script.

but when I exit from the **tftp** prompt, bash prints an error message like

```
get: command not found
quit: command not found
```

So How can I get it done

**EDIT1**:

```
tftp 173.32.52.12 -c get MyFile1.txt MyFile2.txt
tftp 173.32.52.12 -c get MyFile1.txt MyFile2.txt MyFile3.txt etc. etc.
```

these 2 commands not working with my ubuntu(14.0.4) system

Comment: Look into `expect` and similar tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
file1_in_remote location = "/tftpboot/file1.txt"
file2_in_local_machine = "/home/file2.txt"

tftp 172.2.22.2 << !
#file names can be stored in varible
get ${file1_in_remote location} ${file2_in_local_machine}     
quit
!
```

This worked for me

And There is one more solution

```
tftp 172.2.22.2 << 'EOF'
#explictely specify the file names. varibales wont accept here.
get /tftpboot/file1.txt /home/file2.txt  
quit
EOF
```

but in second solution you have to give the file location explicit. And in the 1st solution file name can be stored in variable and we can use that variable in the "*get*" command.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [atftp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/atftp.1.html)

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install atftp
```

Use:

```
atftp 172.2.22.2 -g -r /remote/file.txt -l /tmp/local.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The tftp is a tiny ftp variant and there is several implementations of this client protocol. The tftp-hpa package has a command option (-c) that make this possible as an one-liner in a script. Tested on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
apt install tftp-hpa
tftp 172.2.22.2 -c get /tftpboot/file1.txt /home/file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

another single line option:

```
printf "bin\nget file.txt\n" | tftp 172.2.22.2
```